# AJAX/JavaScript/Python - Calling a JavaScript function on a html page, from a Python file?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I have 3 scripts which I am using in a Python Flask app:

- `home.html`
- `update_progress.html`
- `views.py`

In `views.py` file, I have a function which updates a variable in my `update_progress.html`

```
@views.route('/update_progress', methods=['POST'])
def updateprogress():
    value = 20
    return jsonify('', render_template('update_progress.html', x=value))
```

The `update_progress.html` is blank except this:

```
<div id="update_progress">
{{ x }}
</div>
```

And all this is called by a JavaScript function in my `home.html`:

```
$(function loadValue() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/update_progress",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $(update_progress).replaceWith(data)
                    }
                });
            });
```

If I call the JavaScript function within `home.html` with a `window.setInterval(function())` it works, and the `x` within `update_progress.html` is replaced with the value 20.

However, what I actually need is to call the JavaScript loadvalue() function from within another function inside `views.py` - lets call it `doTasks()`, which contains various tasks.  I want it to be called before `doTasks()` finishes.

I have spent the last few hours trying to do this, but nothing seems to work and am close to giving up. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can't call the code in the browser from the server.. .because pythin doesn't run on a browser (yet)

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I am working with a Python Flask Web app.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your comment. You mean it is impossible to call a JavaScript function on a HTML page from a Python Script inside the same web app?

Comment: Python runs where? On the server or the client (browser on someone elses computer)

Comment: I have a hosted linux server on the web, so the Python runs there.

Comment: So. Not in the browser. Where the JavaScript is

Comment: Correct, so on my hosted linux server I have my html templates which has some JS in it, and some Python files. And the html is rendered through Flask by my Python files

Comment: And sent to the browser where the js isn't just a bunch of characters but an actual program with functions that can not be called from the server since they exist only on the browser

Comment: So the html files sit on my server, and within them are  various JavaScript functions. Some of which call my Python Functions.

Comment: No. JavaScript can't call python either. Except through ajax sort of

Comment: Client (js) can initiate communication with server (python) through ajax. But neither directly "call functions" on the other. And server cant initiate the exchange. Except maybe with websocket ... but thats advanced

Comment: But I am using AJAX. It is in my title? The  JS function I have in my question is calling the Python function I have in my question, and it works fine. I just want to do it the other way around but from a different Python function

Comment: Ahh, ok, so it is communicating with Python through AJAX. Got it, thank you. But I am guessing I cannot do it the other way around?

Comment: With websockets ... or server sent events

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at websockets, thank you! :)

Comment: @Nicholas Python scripts only run on the server at the current time, not in the browser locally where the JavaScript is executing. Perhaps you should look into [Server-sent events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) to be used for sending multiple replies back from `doTasks`. The first reply would be something that would cause the JavaScript code receiving the reply to invoke the **update_progress** view and the second reply would be the results containing whatever `doTasks`normally returns.

Comment: Thank you Booboo, really appreciate the advice and knowledge transfer.